# Python Django Gmail SMTP setup

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, gmail

I am trying to send email from Django by setting up gmail smtp.
But everytime it is returning me 0 status. I have searched different relevant answers in stackoverflow and i am setting up the smtp server the same way but still it is not sending any email..
Below is my setting file

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my gmail account'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my gmail account password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'my gmail account'
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = 'to email'
```

Below is my code

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
print "Sending Email"
mail_title = 'Test Email'
message = 'This is a test email.' 
email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
recipients = [settings.DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL]
print send_mail(mail_title, message, email, recipients, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD) 
print "Email Sent"
```

But everytime it print status 0 which means email is not sent. About the environment i am running this code on Amazon EC2 instance which has ubuntu as an OS and Apache as server..

Do i need to do additional setups for sending email through gmail smtp??
Much appreciate your help
Thanks in advance

Comment: does this code work on your own workstation or somewhere else than your EC2 ? this will permit to isolate the origin of the issue

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your `gmail.smtp` setup is correct.  It looks like you are not calling the `send_email` function correctly, and that's why it's not sending.  In the python shell, try the following:

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change EMAIL_USE_TLS=True to EMAIL_USE_SSL=True and  EMAIL_PORT=465

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/