# Django: configuring email sending

Tags: django

I am in new  Django framework. I want to send an e-mail. This is my `setting.py` file and I want to know what should I put at `EMAIL_HOST`,  `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` fields. Could you explain what is this?

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
EMAIL_HOST = ''
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything depend what email service you want to use. Example for GMAIL you can find here [Python Django Gmail SMTP setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264907/python-django-gmail-smtp-setup)