# django - sending email with gmail failure

Tags: python, django, django-email

I'm trying to implement an automatic email sending system with gmail on my django app.

This is my view:

```
from .forms import EmailPostForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def post_share(request, post_id):
    #retrive post by #
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, status='published')
    sent=False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Form was submitted
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Form passes validation
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            #...send Email
            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
            subject = f"{cd['name']} recomends you read {post.title}"
            message = f" Read {post.title} at {post_url}\n\n" \
                      f" {cd['name']}\s comments: {cd['comments']}"
            send_mail = (subject, message, 'my_gmail_acccount@gmail.com', [cd['to']])
            sent=True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'post':post,
        'sent': sent
        }
    return render(request, 'byExample_django3/post/share.html', context)
```

and my form:

```
from django import forms

class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    to = forms.EmailField()
    comments= forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

and my template:

```
{% extends "byExample_django3/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Share a post{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  {% if sent %}
    <h1>E-mail successfully sent</h1>
    <p>
      "{{ post.title }}" was successfully sent to {{ form.cleaned_data.to }}.
    </p>
  {% else %}
    <h1>Share "{{ post.title }}" by e-mail</h1>
    <form method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="Send e-mail">
    </form>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

and my url:

```
path('<int:post_id>/share', views.post_share, name='post_share')
```

I think I have configured my settings correctly:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_gmail_account@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='my_password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I tried first on the django shell with send_mail:

```
send_mail = ('django test mail', 'django test mail content', 'my_gmail_account@gmail.com', ['my_gmail_account@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False])
```

and everything worked correctly, but when I try it on the browser, I receive the message that email was sent but nothing happens.

Any help?

thank you very much

Carlo

Comment: You have not specified email backend

Comment: send_mail is a function, you should call it as send_mail((subject, message, 'my_gmail_acccount@gmail.com', [cd['to']]))

Comment: Unfortunately it does not make any difference adding the double parenthesis,

Comment: @SachinYadav do I have to specify it since I'm using gmail? I read in other discussions, it is not necessary. for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264907/python-django-gmail-smtp-setup

Comment: Plus it works correctly when I try the send_mail function from the shell, but it does not work from the browser

Comment: As @IamFr0ssT has mentioned the send_mail is a function and you are using it as a variable read https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_sending_emails.htm

Comment: thank you, I'll look into it tomorrow and let know. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

In fail_silently, you have an extra ']'.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33946653)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).